# How can I preview a compressed object in Amazon AWS S3?

Tags: amazon-s3, compression

We have very large compressed files that a partner put in S3 for us.  We would like to run MapReduce jobs on these files, but they are too large to download to one of our nodes for inspection.  How can we quickly inspect the files to understand how to write MapReduce jobs ingesting them?

Answer (score 0):

We used the following command.  Of course you would need to adjust the decompression step as appropriate for the compression format of the file.  You must ensure that the initial `count` is large enough so that enough of your compressed file is piped into the decompression algorithm for it to begin decompression.  In the case of GZIP, it has a header at the beginning of the file.  This command would fail if the initial `count` were not large enough to get the header to the GZIP command.  Also, the second `count` need not equal the first.  The actual amount of data to read will be the first `count` divided by the compression ratio, but so long as both of these numbers are sufficiently large, you will get your preview of the file.

```
aws s3 cp s3://yer-bucket/path-to/yer/object.gz - | dd ibs=1024 count=1000 | gzip -cd | dd ibs=1024 count=1000
```